# How can I unit test pub/sub using QUnit (or another js unit testing framework)

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, asynchronous, publish-subscribe, qunit

Like the title says, I'd like to put my javascript under unit test, how can I isolate my $.publish() and $.subscribe() calls? I'm using QUnit right now, but only have a few tests, so I'd be willing to change frameworks if required.

Answer (score 1):

Just use http://sinonjs.org/

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code:

```
test( "Should call a subscriber with standard matching": function () {
    var spy = sinon.spy();

    PubSub.subscribe( "message", spy );
    PubSub.publishSync( "message", { id: 45 } );

    assertTrue( spy.calledWith( { id: 45 } ) );
});
```

This is using SinonJs. Follow https://addyosmani.com/blog/unit-testing-backbone-js-apps-with-qunit-and-sinonjs/ for more such example.